# Invalid postback or callback argument error in JMETER

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter

I recorded a .net application using JMETER. After correlating and playing back it throws the below error. I have seen few posts which says eventvalidation has to be set false. Is there any other way to get rid of this error in Jmeter?

```
505|error|500|Invalid postback or callback argument.
```

Event validation is enabled using `<pages enableEventValidation="true"/>` in configuration or `<%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %>` in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.

If the data is valid and expected, use the `ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation` method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you're either missing or passing incorrect [ASP.NET Viewstate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx)

Basically it's an input of "hidden" type which is required to store application state and some service data which you application is expecting.

My understanding is that you're either using kind of hard-coded or recorded viewstate value or totally missing it.

I recommend to append [Regular Expression Extractor](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65150-using-regex-regular-expression-extractor-with-jm) Post Processor (or any suitable kind of post-processors line Beanshell, BSF, XPath - if your application talks XHTML) to extract viewstate value from each request, store it in a variable and add it to every next request.

Comment: I added Regular expression extractor for all the VIEWSTATE and EVENTVALIDATIONs and tested the regular expression using Regular expression Tester. But still the error exists.

Comment: So how did you fix it finally @user2995137

Comment: @MoumitMondal check out [ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter) guide, it contains comprehensive information on necessary correlation for ASP.NET appications.

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable event validation in the config

Comment: This sounds like it's opening up a security risk.

Answer (score 0):

If the dynamic DropDownList in your page, you can try to set blank to the value of  DropDownList in JMeter post data. I think this problem can be solved.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please consider explaining your answer more fully. It isn't clear what it has to do with the question.